# Can I change ESLint's behavior so it runs on save if it's been installed with the "on commit" option

Tags: vue.js, eslint

Maybe I'm blind but I can't see anything about this on https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/ or https://eslint.org/. Maybe the only way is to uninstall it then reinstall it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you have tried this but found it in the [docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/eslint.html#injected-commands)

ESLint can be configured via .eslintrc or the eslintConfig field in package.json.

Lint-on-save during development with eslint-loader is enabled by default. It can be disabled with the lintOnSave option in vue.config.js:

```
//vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: true
}
```

So instead of disabling it you just set it to true.

make sure you do this in a `vue.config.js` file in the root of your directory if you try it.